# removing mustUnderstand attribute from soap headers

Tags: java, soap, axis

How to remove mustunderstand attribute from soap header in axis client.even i dont set it especially, when i set soap header info mustundertand and actor attributes are automatically added to soap message.Does anybody know how to remove them ? 
I am using Axis2 1.4 version's wsdl2java to create my ws client.

Answer (score 8):

None of those solutions worked for me, as:

- I am working with Axis (not Axis2)
- I don't want the attribute to be specified at all, as my server counterpart doesn't support it ("The 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:mustUnderstand' attribute is not declared" is a typical answer in such a case).

Looking at the answer to "[Adding ws-security to wsdl2java generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266237/adding-ws-security-to-wsdl2java-generated-classes/14332481#14332481)" helped me to write a solution that worked for me:

```
void addSecurityHeader(Stub stub, final String username, final String password) {
  QName headerName = new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security");  // Or any other namespace that fits in your case
  AtomicReference<SOAPHeaderElement> header 
    = new AtomicReference<SOAPHeaderElement>
        (new SOAPHeaderElement(headerName) {                       
           {  
             SOAPElement utElem = addChildElement("UsernameToken");
             utElem.addChildElement("Username").setValue(username);
             utElem.addChildElement("Password").setValue(password);
           }
           @Override
           public void setAttribute(String namespace, String localName, String value) {
             if (!Constants.ATTR_MUST_UNDERSTAND.equals(localName)) {  // Or any other attribute name you'd want to avoid
               super.setAttribute(namespace, localName, value);
             }
           }
        });
  SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = header.get();
  soapHeaderElement.setActor(null);      // No intermediate actors are involved.
  stub.setHeader(soapHeaderElement);  // Finally, attach the header to the stub
}
```

Comment: saves my life... thnx

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks. I didn't want any child nodes, hence I used this: new SOAPHeaderElement(
    headerName) {
   {
    setValue(value);
   }

Comment: Thanks! This one should be accepted as a valid answer for this question. The SOAPHeaderElement class adds by default mustUnderstand and actor attributes to the header, and this is (so far) the only way to remove it, by filtering adding/setting it in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to disable the must understand check in the AXIS client you have
to add the following line to your code:

```
_call.setProperty(Call.CHECK_MUST_UNDERSTAND, new Boolean(false));
```

then the **MustUnderstandChecker** of the AXIS Client is never invoked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked manually remove the attribute from the **SOAPHeader**

```
SOAPHeader header = env.getHeader();
OMChildrenQNameIterator childrenWithName = (OMChildrenQNameIterator) header.getChildrenWithName(omElementauthentication.getQName());
    while (childrenWithName.hasNext()) {
        org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement omElement = (org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement) childrenWithName.next();
        QName mustAnderstandQName = omElement.resolveQName("soapenv:mustUnderstand");
        if (mustAnderstandQName == null) {
            continue;
        }
        OMAttribute mustAnderstandAttribute = omElement.getAttribute(mustAnderstandQName);
            if (mustAnderstandAttribute == null) {
                continue;
            }
        omElement.removeAttribute(mustAnderstandAttribute);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was recently struggling with similar situation and by doing some google-ing I managed to find the following solution.

Having used Axis2 you would've probably generated a MyWSStub file that contains the calls to your service.
Create an wrapper class (better not touch the auto-generated stub files) that extends your stub e.g. MyWSStubWrapper:

```
public class MyWSStubWrapper extends MyWSStub {

/**
 * @throws AxisFault
 */
public MyWSStubWrapper() throws AxisFault {
}

/**
 * @param configurationContext
 * @throws AxisFault
 */
public MyWSStubWrapper(ConfigurationContext configurationContext) throws AxisFault {
    super(configurationContext);
}

/**
 * @param targetEndpoint
 * @throws AxisFault
 */
public MyWSStubWrapper(String targetEndpoint) throws AxisFault {
    super(targetEndpoint);
}

/**
 * @param configurationContext
 * @param targetEndpoint
 * @throws AxisFault
 */
public MyWSStubWrapper(ConfigurationContext configurationContext, String targetEndpoint) throws AxisFault {
    super(configurationContext, targetEndpoint);
}

/**
 * @param configurationContext
 * @param targetEndpoint
 * @param useSeparateListener
 * @throws AxisFault
 */
public MyWSStubWrapper(ConfigurationContext configurationContext, String targetEndpoint, boolean useSeparateListener) throws AxisFault {
    super(configurationContext, targetEndpoint, useSeparateListener);
}

@Override
protected void addHeader(OMElement omElementToadd, SOAPEnvelope envelop, boolean mustUnderstand) {
    SOAPHeaderBlock soapHeaderBlock = envelop.getHeader().addHeaderBlock(omElementToadd.getLocalName(), omElementToadd.getNamespace());
    OMNode omNode = null;

    // add child elements
    for (Iterator iter = omElementToadd.getChildren(); iter.hasNext();) {
        omNode = (OMNode) iter.next();
        iter.remove();
        soapHeaderBlock.addChild(omNode);
    }

    OMAttribute omatribute = null;
    // add attributes
    for (Iterator iter = omElementToadd.getAllAttributes(); iter.hasNext();) {
        omatribute = (OMAttribute) iter.next();
        soapHeaderBlock.addAttribute(omatribute);
    }
}
```

}

Bear in mind that the above code will completely remove the soapenv:mustUnderstand="0|1" from your headers if you wish to added you need to call soapHeaderBlock.setMustUnderstand(true|false); somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you using the Axis SOAPHeaderElement and if so, are you setting the mustUnderstand setter to false?

2) Since you're generating your client with wsdl2java, it's quite possible that the WSDL (or more accurately, the schema) contains the mustUnderstand attribute on an element referenced in your SOAP binding.  So when wsdlToJava generates the client code, those attributes will naturally be added.  See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-wsdl20-extensions-20040803/#adf-mu-att) for a description of the mustUnderstand attribute.
If modifying the WSDL is out of the question, and you must remove this attribute from the header, then I suppose you can try to do it with a handler

3) Not advisable, but if you really MUST remove this attribute then I suppose you can add a client side handler that alters the header: http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/handlers/package-summary.html

Comment: 1)Yes I am using SOAPHeaderElement but i tried with both with not setting mustunderstand and settign it to false.nothing changed actually. my code like this:  SOAPHeaderElement header = new SOAPHeaderElement(
      "ns1://x.x.x.x/abc.asmx", "AuthHeader");
  SOAPElement node = header.addChildElement("user_1");
  node.addTextNode("abc");
  SOAPElement node2 = header.addChildElement("pass_1");
  node2.addTextNode("123");
  _call.addHeader(header);

Comment: When you say nothing changed, do you mean that the SOAP header is always showing up with mustUnderstand=false?  Do you have the WSSDL/schema you could post (don't post the whole thing if it's very long... just relevant sections).

Comment: yes i mean exactly that.i think axis codes add mustunderstand and actor properties in default behaviour when soap header parameter set.When i remove the code for soap header than mustunderstand and actor parameters also removed.

Comment: related wsdl part may be   <wsdl:operation name="xMethod">
   <soap:operation
    soapAction="http://x.x.x.x/Bank.asmx/xMethod"
    style="document" />
   <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
    <soap:header
     message="tns:AuthHeader"
     part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>

Answer (score 0):

i am using axis 1.4 client with ws security

in my case as Reinhard said
this worked

```
MyService service = new MyServiceLocator(); 
MyServicePortType port = service.getMyServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint();

((Stub) port)._setProperty(Call.CHECK_MUST_UNDERSTAND, Boolean.FALSE);
```