# Modify Soap header in SoapHandler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapheader

I am trying to modify a soap header, and i want header to be like this

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns:authnHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="http://webservices.averittexpress.com/authn">
                <Username>xxxxxxxx</Username>
                <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
            </ns:authnHeader>
```

This is what i have done till now...

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();

    header.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:soapenc"), "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
    header.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsd"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    header.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:xsi"), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

SOAPElement authnHeader = header.addChildElement("authnHeader", "ns" , "http://webservices.averittexpress.com/authn");

authnHeader.addAttribute(new QName("soapenv:mustUnderstand"), "0");
```

But I am getting

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create
>   or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to
>   namespaces.

at first header.addAttribute.

Please help.

My Import Statements

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.PortInfo;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
```

Comment: Is it possible that you must first remove the old header attributes before adding new ones?  Have a look at this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473145/removing-mustunderstand-attribute-from-soap-headers

Comment: by default there are no attributes.

Comment: Try adding each attribute, one by itself at a time, and see whether you can set any attribute on your header.

Comment: Also please show us your import statements for SOAP and also which JAR you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to define namespace attributes in the SOAP header.  Namespace attributes `xmlns` **must** be defined in the SOAP envelope.  So the XML SOAP envelope you really want would look something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns:authnHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="http://webservices.averittexpress.com/authn">
            <Username>xxxxxxxx</Username>
            <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
        </ns:authnHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <!-- your content goes here -->
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

According to [conventions](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_envelope.asp) if your XML does not give a SOAP namespace in the envelope applications may reject your SOAP message.

For reference, I spent about 3 hours trying to find one code example where someone calls `header.addAttribute()` on a SOAP header, and I could not find even one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had some luck.

This code works

```
Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

if(outboundProperty.booleanValue())
{

   try
    {
         SOAPHeader header = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();

         SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
         SOAPElement authnHeader = soapFactory.createElement("authnHeader", "ns", "http://webservices.averittexpress.com/authn");

         SOAPElement username = authnHeader.addChildElement("Username");
         username.setTextContent("xxxxxxx");

         SOAPElement password = authnHeader.addChildElement("Password");
         password.setTextContent("xxxxxxx");

         header.addChildElement(authnHeader);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After adding header do not forget to save the message

```
context.getMessage().saveChanges();
```

or

```
context.getMessage().writeTo(System.out);
```

also saves message if any changes are done.